# What happened to WellFormedWeb and why is it still in so many XML declarations?

Tags: xml, web, xml-parsing, rss, feed

I'm working on a podcast feed generator and everywhere I look I see XML declarations which include `xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"`. But, the URL wellformedweb.org isn't even active anymore.

Try as I might, I haven't been able to dig up any resources about what the deal is with this declaration. Apple's [RSS feed requirements webpage](https://podcasters.apple.com/support/823-podcast-requirements) does not include this tag, so I'm somewhat assuming it's a legacy piece of the old web which no longer does anything. This has left me interested in at least getting a history lesson though.

What was WellFormedWeb.org? Is this some long-dead project of the old web which has been copy-pasted into eternal glory? Or is this tag actually doing something even though it links to a nonexistent website?

Comment: I'm curios about the history as well.  This is the best I could find on what it is for: https://web.archive.org/web/20050301040756/http://www.sellsbrothers.com/spout/#exposingRssComments

The Comment API allows posting and fetching comments, which IMHO really nice.  Not many blogging system support `wfw:comments` anymore, but `wfw:commentRss` are still widely available and some feed reader (e.g. Liferea) can display them.